# CloudFormation passing variables from one stack to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a situation where I want to pass the output parameter from one stack to the Parameters of another stack.  I know about the Outputs area and the Fn::ImportValue but I have to declair a separate variable in stack #2 or else I get errors.

In Stack 1:

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Default: production
    Description: "A friendly environment name that will be used for namespacing all cluster resources. Example: staging, qa, or production"

...

Outputs:
  EnvironmentName:
    Description: The deployment mode of this and subsequent stacks.
    Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
    Export:
      Name: !Ref EnvironmentName
```

In stack #2 I have:

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Default: production
    Description: "A friendly environment name that will be used for namespacing all cluster resources. Example: staging, qa, or production"
```

I would like to have the Environment name not having to be declared twice.  But I can't do:

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Default: Fn::ImportValue {$EnvironmentName}
    Description: "A friendly environment name that will be used for namespacing all cluster resources. Example: staging, qa, or production"
```

There are a few things I could try, one post suggested using FindInMap and put the env names in the map.  That just seems odd and again, I've not tried that.  The other method is Nested Stacks but I don't want to end up with one huge template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. It simply **not possible** and CFN does not support functions in Parameter defaults or Mappings.

Comment: I kinda figured that, I searched for hours and came up with nothing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I pass parameters from the parent stack to the child stack using the AWS CLI, which allows. Here is the shell command to get the paramters from the parent stack in the required format (`key1=value1 key2=value2 ...`):

```bash
PARENT_OUTPUT_PARAMETERS=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name $(PARENT_STACK_NAME) --query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[*].join(`=`,[OutputKey,OutputValue])' --output text)
```

and then I pass them to the dependent stack:

```bash
aws --region us-east-1 cloudformation deploy \
            --stack-name my-stack \
            --template-file my.template \
            --parameter-overrides $(PARENT_OUTPUT_PARAMETERS) {...other parameters}
```

This requires consistent naming of the outputs and inputs of the two templates, but that is probably a Good Thing.

It also keeps the two templates totally decoupled without explicit references between them.